# Javascript regex trying to escape /**

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a javascript regex and when trying to achieve `/**`, I keep getting `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:`

Does not work

```
\/\*\*
```

Works

```
\/\* \*
```

Is there a special way to escape 2 stars next to each other?

**Bigger picture:**

I'm using [this](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/assert.html#fileContent) yeoman helper to assert this:

```
var expected = "\n\
\/\*\*\n\
\* This is my description\n\
\*\n\
\* @param req\n\
\* @param reply\n\
\*\/\n\
exports.findEm = function (req, reply) {\n\
\n\
itemDao.findEm(req.params.id, function (err, data) {\n\
if (err) {\n\
return reply(Boom.wrap(err));\n\
}\n\
reply(data);\n\
});\n\
};\n\
";

....

helpers.assertFileContent(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'myfile.js'), RegExp(expected));
```

Comment: Where does it not work? It works fine, you could use `\/\*{2}`

Comment: `/\/\*\*/` works fine.

Comment: `"/**".match(/\/\*\*/)` works just fine here. Did anybody mention that already? ;-)

Comment: @Catfish, just to be sure: you did wrap the both patterns you posted in `/…/`, right?

Comment: I'm using this yeoman helper http://yeoman.github.io/generator/assert.html#fileContent

Comment: Are you passing the regex as a string? Then you have to escape the backslash with another backslash: `"\\/\\*\\*"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do pass the regex as a string. You have to escape the backslash with another backslash: `"\\/\\*\\*"`.

But your regex contains many meaningful characters that you need to escape, too. E.g. parentheses are for grouping and capturing; and braces are to replicate a pattern (`a{3}` = three `a`s). I.e. do a find and replace: `{` → `\\{`, `[` → `\\[`,  `(` → `\\(`, `.` → `\\.`.

And having newlines in the expression will probably not work either.

Comment: So if I do that, I don't get a syntax error, but I get an assertionError that contains slashes in the output. `AssertionError: /temp/modules/items/item-ctrl.js did not match '/
\/\*\*
* This is my description
*
* @param req
* @param reply
*/
exports.findEm = function (req, reply) {

itemDao.findEm(req.params.id, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
return reply(Boom.wrap(err));
}
reply(data);
});
};
/'.`

Comment: Ahhh it was the double escape on the parens that got me. Thanks!